# Xml Merge Multiple Xmls into a new Xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I am trying to merge multiple xml into a skeleton xml file to create a new XML File. I am trying to create a loop to include multiple xmls and merge into one xml. I am trying something like this but it is not working
:File dir = new File("E:\temp\");
        File[] rootFiles = dir.listFiles();
So far I am not able to create correct xml with single XML. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code with single xml input :

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    File file = new File("Result.xml");



        String baseXml = "E:\\IntelliJ\\TryXml\\src\\blank.xml";
        String inputXmls = "E:\\IntelliJ\\TryXml\\src\\input1.xml";

        Document doc1 = db.parse(baseXml);
        Document doc2 = db.parse(inputXmls);

        NodeList nList = doc1.getElementsByTagName("Configs");

        Element element = (Element) nList.item(0);

        Node copiedNode = doc2.importNode(element, true);

        doc2.getDocumentElement().appendChild(copiedNode);

        processXml(doc2, file);
}

private static void processXml(Document xml, File file) throws TransformerException {
    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,"UTF-8");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"yes");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
    tf.transform(source,result);
}
```

XML Files

Input1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>
        <Config name="test1">
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author1</author>
        </Config>
        <Config name="test2">
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <author>Author2</author>
        </Config>
    </Configs>
    <optional>I dont want this to be copied</optional>
    <Ratings>
        <body>
            <Items name = "object 1">
                <something1>something1</something1>
            </Items>
        </body>
    </Ratings>
</rss>
```

Input2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>
        <Config name="test3">
            <title>Title 3</title>
            <author>Author3</author>
        </Config>
        <Config name="test4">
            <title>Title 4</title>
            <author>Author4</author>
        </Config>
    </Configs>
    <optional>I dont want this to be copied</optional>
    <Ratings>
        <body>
            <Items name = "object 2">
                <something1>something2</something1>
            </Items>
        </body>
    </Ratings>
</rss>
```

blank.xml (skeleton xml where I will be inserting the elements according to the tags)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>

    </Configs>
    <Ratings>
        <body>

        </body>
    </Ratings>
</rss>
```

This is what i am getting

Result.xml

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>
        <Config name="test1">
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author1</author>
        </Config>
        <Config name="test2">
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <author>Author2</author>
        </Config>
    </Configs>
    <optional>I dont want this to be copied</optional>
    <Ratings>
        <body>
            <Items name="object 1">
                <something1>something1</something1>
            </Items>
        </body>
    </Ratings>
<Configs>

    </Configs>
</rss>
```

This is what I need

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>
            <Config name="test1">
                <title>Title 1</title>
                <author>Author1</author>
            </Config>
            <Config name="test2">
                <title>Title 2</title>
                <author>Author2</author>
            </Config>
            <Config name="test3">
                <title>Title 3</title>
                <author>Author3</author>
            </Config>
            <Config name="test4">
                <title>Title 4</title>
                <author>Author4</author>
            </Config>
        </Configs>
        <Ratings>
            <body>
                <Items name="object 1">
                    <something1>something1</something1>
                </Items>
                <Items name="object 2">
                    <something1>something2</something1>
                </Items>
            </body>
        </Ratings>
    </rss>
```

**Update**
This is what I got without the updated value between the  tag.

This is how I defined the Items as NodeList

```
NodeList itemsNodeList = inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("Items");


<rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>

    <Config name="test1">
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author1</author>
        </Config>
<Config name="test2">
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <author>Author2</author>
        </Config>
<Config name="test3">
            <title>Title 3</title>
            <author>Author3</author>
        </Config>
<Config name="test4">
            <title>Title 4</title>
            <author>Author4</author>
        </Config>
</Configs>
    <Ratings>
        <body>

        <Items name="object 1">
                <something1>something1</something1>
            </Items>
<Items name="object 2">
                <something1>something2</something1>
            </Items>
</body>
    </Ratings>
</rss>
```

Comment: I think the main issue is that you use doc2 document for modification (creating result) instead of doc1 ( blank) and other issues in the logic

Comment: do you still need Java solution for that?

Comment: Yes, still looking for Java solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java solution:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

File file = new File("Result.xml");

String baseXml = "blank.xml";

String[] inputXmls = {"input1.xml","input2.xml"};

Document resultDoc = db.parse(baseXml);

Node resultConfigsNode = resultDoc.getElementsByTagName("Configs").item(0);
Node resultRatingsBodyNode = resultDoc.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);

for (String inputXml : inputXmls){
    Document inputDoc = db.parse(inputXml);

    NodeList configNodeList = inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("Config");

    for (int i = 0; i < configNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node copiedNode = resultDoc.importNode(configNodeList.item(i), true);
        resultConfigsNode.appendChild(copiedNode);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node copiedNode = resultDoc.importNode(itemsNodeList.item(i), true);
        NamedNodeMap attrMap = copiedNode.getAttributes();
        Node n = attrMap.getNamedItem("name");
        if(n.getNodeValue().equals("object 1")){
            System.out.println("Items object 1");
        }
        resultRatingsBodyNode.appendChild(copiedNode);
    }

    NodeList valueNodeList = inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("value");
    for (int i = 0; i < valueNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node copiedNode = resultDoc.importNode(valueNodeList.item(i), true);
        Text txt = (Text) copiedNode.getFirstChild();
        txt.setData("NewValue");
        resultRatingsBodyNode.appendChild(copiedNode);
    }

}
processXml(resultDoc, file);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. If i have more items inside <body> such as <body><Items name="object 1">
                <something1>something1</something1>
            </Items><value>someValue</value><body> and I have to change the value of SomeValue to NewValue, how can I update it? Can I reference to Items name="object 1", and update the value inside the first value tag i find?

Comment: Please see updated version with example how to  change the value of SomeValue to NewValue and reference to Items name="object 1"

Comment: Hello Sergey, I tried your updated code but it did not update the value inside the <something1> tags. I have updated my result.

Comment: @404or505 hi! please check impl https://github.com/sbzDev/stackoverflow/tree/master/question56248965

Comment: I cannot thank you enough.. It is what I need. For some reason, I was looking for <something1> tag instead of <value> tag. Really appreciate your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Use XSLT for this kind of job, it will make your life much easier (XSLT can be invoked easily from Java). With blank.xml as your principal input document, it can be done like this in XSLT 3.0 (and isn't much harder using 1.0 or 2.0):

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:param name="input1" select="doc('input1.xml')"/>
<xsl:param name="input2" select="doc('input2.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="Configs">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="$input1//Config, $input2//Config"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="$input1//Items, $input2//Items"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. Can we merge n numbers of XML files and not just 2 or 5 files? And will I be able to change value such as <Items name="object 1"> to <Items name="object x"> or <author>Author4</author> to <author>Author10</author> during the merge process? I am not too familiar with XSLT, I will give it a try. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Yes, all those things are possible. If you have specific problems doing any of these things, then ask a specific question on a new thread.